# Pause function while another function finishes

Tags: javascript, callback

Im struggling with this code:

Within 'swapFunc' function, I append an addEventListener to 'tEleBaby' element, immediately after which, I trigger the addEventListener by replacing the class of 'tEleBaby'.

The problem is with the code within 'setTimeout', which needs to run after the 'animListener' function has completed. Im not keen on using setTimeout so would prefer a more sensible / correct way of dealing with this.

```
swapFunc: function swapFunc(tEle, swapEle) {
    var tEle = document.getElementById(tEle);
    var tEleBaby = tEle.children[0];
    tEleBaby.addEventListener("animationend", this.animListener, false);
    tEleBaby.classList.add("animFadeOut");
    // I want to remove the setTimeout; i.e. the animListener func should feedback to swapFunc
    setTimeout(function () {
        tEle.id = swapEle;
        tEle.setAttribute("data-action", dataAction);
        tEle.setAttribute("data-tooltip", dataTooltip);
    }, 500);
},

animListener: function animListener(ev) {
    if (ev.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("animationend") >= 0) {
        var eventTarget = ev.target;
        eventTarget.className = "animFadeIn cFBIcons";
    }
},
```

Comment: I don't really get why you selected that answer. This approach is quite counter intuitive and adds complexity to the code without giving any benefits. Why having a callback for a synchronous function?

Comment: No Benefits, agreed. But the question clearly asks if the `function can be called as a callback`. Maybe the OP wishes to add an async function later, or maybe OP just wishes to get an idea... It's always best not to assume things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way :

```
swapFunc: function swapFunc(tEle, swapEle) {
    var tEle = document.getElementById(tEle);
    var tEleBaby = tEle.children[0];
    tEleBaby.addEventListener("animationend", listener, false);
    tEleBaby.classList.add("animFadeOut");

    function listener(ev) {
        animListener(ev, callMe);
    }

    function callMe() {
        tEle.id = swapEle;
        tEle.setAttribute("data-action", dataAction);
        tEle.setAttribute("data-tooltip", dataTooltip);
    }
},

animListener: function animListener(ev, callback) {
    if (ev.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("animationend") >= 0) {
        var eventTarget = ev.target;
        eventTarget.className = "animFadeIn cFBIcons";
    }
    callback();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply put that code in the event handler?

```
var self = this;

tEleBaby.addEventListener ("animationend" , function (ev) {
    self.animListener(ev);
    //rest of code
} , false);
```